# How to deal with paired values?

Tags: matlab, accumarray

Say I have a vector of independent variable values

```
v =[ 1 2 2 1 1 .5 1 2 .5 .5 1]
```

and a vector of response variables

```
u = [ 5 22 20 4 8 .2 5 12 0 .5 6]
```

I want to plot `u` vs. `v` with errorbars, the method needs to work for 100s of possible values for the independent variable. The problem isn't in plotting the error bars, it's in how can I create a vector pair `[mean(u(find(v==0.5)), mean(u(find(v==1)), mean(u(find(v==2))]`. Is there a standard automated way of doing this other than sorting `v`, then picking out the values of sorted `v` and finding the index of `v` where `v` matches those values? This seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are after if you want to get the means for each unique value of `v` in the order in which the unique values appear in `v`:

```
>> [unv,iunv,iv] = unique(v);
>> umeans = accumarray(iv(:),u,[],@mean);
>> [~,ivorder] = sort(iunv);
>> umeans = umeans(ivorder)

umeans =

    5.6000
   18.0000
    0.2333
```

If you want the means in order of the sorted values of `v`, then just use the output of `accumarray` without the reordering commands:

```
>> [unv,iunv,iv] = unique(v);
>> umeans = accumarray(iv(:),u,[],@mean)

umeans =

    0.2333
    5.6000
   18.0000
```

Just ensure that `u` is a row vector.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I did not know about the unique function. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: @user1544793: Glad to help.  Out of curiosity, did you want it the first way?

Comment: That doesn't matter so much the plotting function won't care about the ordering as long as the pairing is consistent. Probably the sorted way is cleaner for other applications though.

Comment: @user1544793: I see.  Sounds like you will be plotting against `unv`, which contains the sorted unique values in `v`, or against `unv(ivorder)` for the unique values in `v` in the order in which they appear in `v`.